# Shiny: unable to render a js file

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to build a video retrieval system using tags on Shiny. I have been able to crack most parts of it, except for rendering the videos in a loop. I tried looking up and found that if I can replicate the following HTML code in R shiny syntax I will be sorted with my code.

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')**

HTML CODE

```
<html>
<head>

<video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="myvideo" width="320" height="240" controls style="background:black">
</video>


<div>
<span>ADD in any button or anything here what you want </span>
<span> You entire HTML content goes here </span>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');
var myvids = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", 
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
  ];
var activeVideo = 0;

myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  // update the active video index
  activeVideo = (++activeVideo) % myvids.length;

  // update the video source and play
  myvid.src = myvids[activeVideo];
  myvid.play();
});

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Equivalent Shiny Code

```
ui <- navbarPage("",
                 tabPanel("exp",id = 'exp',
                          fluidPage(
                            tags$script(src ="hope.js"),
                           fluidRow("i",uiOutput("vid"))
                          ))
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {

    output$vid <- renderUI({
      tags$video(id='myvideo',type = 'video/mp4',src = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",controls="controls",controlsList="nodownload",loop = "loop",
                 autoplay ="autoplay",muted="muted")
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Could someone help me solve this error?

Comment: what's in `hope.js`

Comment: var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');
var myvids = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", 
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
  ];
var activeVideo = 0;

myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  // update the active video index
  activeVideo = (++activeVideo) % myvids.length;

  // update the video source and play
  myvid.src = myvids[activeVideo];
  myvid.play();
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- navbarPage("",
                 tabPanel("exp",id = 'exp',
                          fluidPage(
                              fluidRow("i",uiOutput("vid"))
                          ))
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    output$vid <- renderUI({
        tagList(
            tags$video(
                id='myvideo',type = 'video/mp4',
                src = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
                controls="controls",controlsList="nodownload", 
                autoplay ="autoplay",muted="muted"),
            tags$script(
                '
                var myvid = document.getElementById("myvideo");
                var myvids = [
                  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", 
                  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
                  ];
                var activeVideo = 0;
                
                myvid.addEventListener("ended", function(e) {
                  // update the active video index
                  console.log("Video stopped")
                  activeVideo = (++activeVideo) % myvids.length;
                
                  // update the video source and play
                  myvid.src = myvids[activeVideo];
                  myvid.play();
                });
                '
            )
        )
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here are the two key points:

1. If you want to use `renderUI`, the script has to go into the render expression as well. You can't leave in the UI. The script is been run when the UI is constructed, but here we want to wait till the `video` tag is rendered.
2. In the `video` tag, you shouldn't use `loop = "loop"`. This will cause the video `"ended"` event to never be triggered (it's looping, but not ending). In the script, the loop behavior is controlled by `myvid.play()` command.

Bonus tip: you may want to set the `width` and `height` of your `video` tag. Different videos have different dimensions. If you let it set automatically, you will see the video element size changes between videos on your UI. Fixing the width and height may give your users a better experience.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable hacks & basics :)